# How can I select multiple columns from a table in R?

Tags: r

Let us assume that I have data stored in a simple list. Let us call this list A. I would like to write a function where I choose the 2nd, 5th, and 10th, items from the list and create a new matrix with that output. For example, `A<-(c(2,5,10))` means I need to choose the 2nd,5th and 10th column to create a new matrix. Assuming that I wanted to call the function choosecol, where `choosecol(data,A)` returns the matrix of output with the values corresponding to the 2nd, 5th, and 10th position. How would I (or should I), write a function that makes this possible?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write a function for this. `data[, A]` should do it:

```
m <- matrix(1:20, ncol = 10)
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17    19
# [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20

A <- c(2, 5, 10)

m[, A]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    9   19
# [2,]    4   10   20
```